# Sitecore 9.0.2 very slow startup

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Does someone has experiences in very slow startup of sitecore 9.0.2 in a new and clear local installation it takes about 5 minutes after I change a config file until sitecore is up and running again.

The instance is fresh installed I've an other local installation which starts in about 1 minute and I am using the same installation script, just the prefix changed. The local system has no  traffic and I can't see any hard cpu usage why the instance startup takes so long.

The logfiles seems to be ok, no exceptions and so on.

If I should post any logfiles and so on please tell me.

I've found the following post on sitecore forums: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/8920 I've tried this but it does not help.

Comment: Did you monitor the Hard Disk? I was facing the same issue, had to upgrade the HDD to SSD. Also, SSD is recommended for Sitecore.

Comment: Yeah, even with that patch there's pretty significant slow-down still, but I did find that memory usage, and application pool destroying CPU spikes, went down. Sitecore just does so much more now than it did before.

Comment: I have a M2 SSD and on my second local instance it works fine don't know why the one is slow

Comment: my system is healing itself, today everything works fine after IIS reset the site is up in 20 seconds. The Only thing I've done yesterday was to restart my pc but that was not the first time of a restart after the performance problems.

Comment: Are you using glass mapper by any chance?

Comment: no glass mapper

Answer (score 0):

As per Sitecore recommendation:

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(On-Prem).pdf

- RAM - 16 GB
- HDD - 500 GB

I started Sitecore 9 Upgrade on my 12 GB Thinkpad but the performance was very slow and utilization level of my CPU was hitting 97%. Then I moved to 16 GB RAM and performance improved after that.

Why we need a high end machine:

- Sitecore 9 comes with xConnect which is hosted as another website in IIS and consumes Memory.
- Solr runs as a window service in Sitecore 9 which again takes more space.
- When Sitecore Commerce is installed then 4 websites get deployed in IIS and they run concurrently so it consumes more memory.

So I recommend you upgrade your machine/server and then try.

Comment: I got 32GB Ram 512GB M2 SSD and Core i7-8700 and in the task manager was no workload it was very curios.

Comment: Can you check  in the log file which process is taking time and if possible you can share as well